# How can I pass an arrayadapter to another activity?

Tags: android

Basically I'm making a battleships game with a messaging system. Therefore I've got another activity that the user can switch back and forth from. So if phone 1 sends a message to phone 2, phone 2 will add the message to an array adapter and then pass that to the new activity when the user goes to the message page. I hope this makes sense.

How can I send my arrayadapter to another activity? Is it something like `intent.putExtra(etc);`. Do I need to save it to an arraylist and convert that to an array adapter in the new activity?

Comment: Well, I'd use SQLite instead of wasting the time for broken approach like this...

Comment: lol I'll look into that thanks. I'm not the best programmer.

Comment: actually can you say quickly why it's broken? How long would implementing SQLite take/is it hard? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should simply pass the underlying data to the other Activity, and have the arrayadapter reload the data. The ArrayAdapter is initialized with the context of the Activity you loaded it with.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest you can do is make the ArrayAdapter serializable. Just implement the interface.

Comment: Hmmm, can you give me some advice quickly, I'm confused. Activity 1 has the game display, which works through bluetooth and is controlled in the handler via checking if string is equal to xyz and do stuff accordingly. Now I want a 2nd activity for messaging, but how would I load the messages there? Everytime a message is sent in activity 2 it will arrive in the handler for activity 1

Comment: Array adapter is an object which provides data for list views. On its own, it does not need any links to the context and should not have any handlers, either, besides `notifyDatasetChanged` / `Invalidated` inherited from `BaseAdapter`. Thus it can live completely independently from an Activity and can be reused by another list view. Just assign the existing adapter to a desired view in the new Activity.

Comment: However, if your message window is a temporary interruption of the game, as I understand it, don't you agree a Dialog might be more appropriate for this task, as well as much easier to implement?